# would connecting a pipe that can carry twice the volume of water to a supply pipe reduce the water pressure in half? If not is there a formula?

Tags: pressure, water

I am trying to reduce water pressure by changing pipe size. I want to make a slow peaceful fountain spray.The end of the water line will be pointed straight up so will the weight of the water play into the water pressure. Does the length of the tube going straight up effect water pressure?

Answer (score -1):

Volume flow rate out per unit time $$Q = \frac{\pi \Delta pR^4}{8 \eta l}$$
where
$\Delta p$ is pressure difference between heads,
$R$ is radius of pipe,
$l$ is length of pipe, and
$\eta$ is viscocity coefficient.

This formula is for a pipe having constant radius throughout, laminar flow and assuming linear change in velocity of liquid from centre (max) to surface of pipe (zero). This is called the Poiseuille equation. For your problem you can assume volume flow rate would remain constant but pressure change how do u change radius and length.